# finding bijections

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Find bijections between A and B and proof their bijectivity

1. $A=\{2m| m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, $B=\{2n-1| n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Here I have $f: A \rightarrow B$,
$f(x)=x-1$. It is easy to prove that it is one to one, and that it is onto.

2. $A=\{3m| m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, $B=\{3n-1| n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \cup \{3k-2|k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

The elements which are in $B$ are the ones $1$ mod $3$ and $2$ mod $3$, but I can not come up with any solutions for (2). Should the function be piecewise there?

Could someone check whether 1) is correct and help me solving 2)?

Comment: 1 is correct.  For 2, have you seen a bijection between all the integers and the even integers?  The idea is the same in that there are "twice as many" integers as even integers.  Of course there are not, as there is a bijection, but you need a multiply by $2$ to create it.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Thank you for checking (1). Would this be the proof for the integers and even integers? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bijection_between_Integers_and_Even_Integers. I understand this proof, but I am having trouble applying it to my case. I think piecewise definition would be easy, but I think an explicit function is asked.

Comment: Yes, that is the one I am thinking of.  Note that a piecewise definition can be an explicit function.  Even numbers -> 1, Odd numbers -> -1 is a fine explicit function

Comment: @RossMillikan: thank you, I was thinking the same in dividing the elements of $A=\{{3m|m \in \mathbb{Z}}\}$ into 0(2) and 1(2), and the ones 0 mod 2 would be mapped onto 3n-1 and those 1(2) onto 3n-2. would this be correct?

Comment: No, because you have $0 \to -1, 3 \to 7, 6 \to 17$ and miss a lot of elements of $B$.

Comment: oh you are right, but how could I then divide the elements of A?

Comment: Dividing them into odds and evens is a good idea.  You need to multiply by $\frac 32$ to get the right density because the odds are spaced by $2$ and the $3n-1$ are spaced by $3$.  The odds can then take $k$ to $\frac 32(k-1)-1$ for example  This takes $1 \to -1, 3 \to 2, 5 \to 5$ and so on.

Comment: @RossMillikan: thank you so much, but what I don't understand is, in the set A, the only numbers which are there, are the multiples of 3, so shouldn't the k's be only the multiples of 3? So we would not have 1 or 5 in the domain?

Comment: I missed that you only had the multiples of $3$ in A.  Then you should just be multiplying by $\frac 12$, so odds go to $\frac 12(k-1)-1$ which gives $1 \to -1, 7 \to 2, 13 \to 5$ and so on.  Now take the evens to the other part of B.

Comment: @RossMillikan, thank you so much for your time, but what I still don't quite get, is shouldn't k itself be only 0(3)? I modified the function, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(k-1)-2$ for me, it would be $3 \rightarrow -1$, $9 \rightarrow 2$, $15 \rightarrow 5$. and the evens would be to $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(k)-2$ , so $0 \rightarrow -2$, $6 \rightarrow 1$, $12 \rightarrow 4$. I think this works now? The difference is always 3? But I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1.$ is correct.  For $2.$, an injection from $A$ to $B$ would be

$f(a)=\dfrac a2+1$ if $a$ is even and $\dfrac{a+1}2$ if $a$ is odd.

Note that $\dfrac{1+(-1)^a}2$ is $1$ when $a$ is even and $0$ when $a$ is odd,

and $\dfrac{1-(-1)^a}2$ is $0$ when $a$ is even and $1$ when $a$ is odd,

so $f(a)=\dfrac{1+(-1)^a}2\left(\dfrac a2+1\right)+\dfrac{1-(-1)^a}2\left(\dfrac {a+1}2\right)$ works,

and that simplifies to $f(a)=\dfrac{2a+3+(-1)^a}4$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!